# How to type useRef hook in Flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I can't figure out how to type a `useRef` hook in Flow. In TS I could just do:

```
const inputRef = useRef<InputRefType>();
```

But this doesn't work in Flow and I'm unsure what to replace it with.

This is what the code looks like:

```
const inputRef = useRef();
return (
  <>
    <input ref={inputRef} name="email" value={email} onChange={handleChange} />
    <button onClick={() => inputRef.current.focus()}>Ref</button>
  </>
);
```

Here is the error message:

```
Cannot call inputRef.current.focus because property focus is missing in null [1]. [incompatible-use]

     src/App.js
      30│       }}
      31│     />
      32│     <input ref={inputRef} name="email" value={email} onChange={handleChange} />
      33│     <button onClick={() => inputRef.current.focus()}>Ref</button>
      34│   </>
      35│ );
      36│ };

     /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_1fa18dde633e97c7_501/react.js
 [1] 197│   | { -current: React$ElementRef<ElementType> | null, ... }
```

Complete App.js file:

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import type { ComponentType } from "react";

const App: ComponentType<{}>  = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e): void => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  }

  const inputRef = useRef();

return (
  <>
    <input ref={inputRef} name="email" value={email} onChange={handleChange} />
    <button onClick={() => inputRef.current.focus()}>Ref</button>
  </>
);
};

export default App;
```

Error:
[image: Picture of error]

Comment: Share your complete `src/App.js` file

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani Added.

Comment: You can take reference from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49248680/flow-type-complains-about-class-property-assigned-via-react-ref

Comment: @sidverma I saw that post already and it didn’t really help. I noticed it recommends to use “ HTMLInputElement” but I don’t know where to import this from.

Comment: check this: https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-componenttype @Jav

Comment: `inputRef.current?.focus()`

Comment: @sidverma I've already seen that article and it doesn't help because I don't know the type of `inputRef`. What is the type returned by `useRef()`?

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this in a number of ways, either you declare the ref as it's type like so

```
const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
```

Because `inputRef` is initially null when you initialise it, so just `HTMLInputRef` would be incorrect. This is a native JS class that can just be used, it's not a flow type.

---

A simpler way is to ignore the declaration and write `inputRef.current?.focus()` as mentioned in the comments and this works fine for this example but is limited by inference because you're never checking or defining the type.

---

Or the other way is through type refinement where instead of just doing a null check you also check for whether it's the type you expect.

```
if (inputRef.current instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
  inputRef.current.focus();
}
```

This protects you against soundness errors in case in the off chance `inputRef.current` is defined but it ends up being a button instead of an input element.

---

The choice is really up to you and depends on your needs. They'll all work for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You should do a null check before calling **inputRef.current?.focus()**

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import type { ComponentType } from "react";

const App: ComponentType<{}> = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

    const handleChange = (e): void => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setEmail(e.target.value);
    }

    const inputRef = useRef();

    return (
        <>
            <input ref={inputRef} name="email" value={email} onChange={handleChange} />
            <button onClick={() => inputRef.current?.focus()}>Ref</button>
        </>
    );
};
```